# in-place message in MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, warnings, message, in-place

Hi 
If any one knows how to use in-place warning message in MFC could you share info. 
Is there a way to use it or is there any control we can use directly in mfc.

In-Place warning message: A warning message with appropriate icon along with warning message, will be displayed with in the same dialog.

I found some info about in-place message in msdn

[InPlace message in msdn glossary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511441.aspx#InPlace)

[Different messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511263.aspx)

Please share information.

Regards

Haranadh

Comment: What does an "in-place message" look like? Can you show us a screenshot of the effect you're looking for? I assume you're not talking about the `AfxMessageBox` function.

Comment: you can refer the link provided in above link -> Different messages. in that link you can refer many message boxes. out of those, refer dialog with a title "connect to a network projector". It has a warning message-> "using unsecured network ..." that message is in-place message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment, it appears that you're referring to this as an in-place message:

[image]

Ironically, of course, that's labeled as the **incorrect** example on the MSDN page that you link to. It's specifically recommended that you provide more specific advice, such as securing the projector with a password so that the presentation is not visible to unintended viewers. Putting that aside, however...

This is quite easy to implement in MFC. It's done simply with two [`STATIC` controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760767.aspx), one on the left that displays an icon (in this case, a warning triangle) and the longer one on the right that displays static text (the warning message itself). If you're using the dialog editor to create your window, it's a simple matter of dragging the two controls to the dialog window and arranging them accordingly. There isn't a single control that encapsulates this functionality, but it's silly to expect that there would be, considering that doing it with two separate static controls is already so straightforward.

To load built-in icons such as the warning triangle shown above, you can use the [`LoadStandardIcon` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44s6bcez.aspx) and specify `IDI_WARNING` as the icon name. The complete list of values is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072.aspx). Obviously you can load any icon of your choosing as well; just add it to your project's resources.

Since you will presumably want to display the warning message only when it's *applicable*, you will need to programmatically hide and show the two controls depending on action taken by the user in your dialog. The standard `ShowWindow` member function makes this a trivial task. Call it on the two static controls, passing `SW_SHOW` as its argument if you want the warning message to be visible. Otherwise, you can specify `SW_HIDE` to hide the control.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to what you are trying to do; you could place your message in a dialog:

```
int nResult = AfxMessageBox("Save changes to Current Job?", MB_YESNO);

    if (nResult == IDYES)
    {
        OnFileSave();
    }
```

Comment: hi, the issue was mainly related to GUI look and feel. but the above answer helped me to try. thanks for ur suggestion.